# Assigning value to an empty variable in a for loop in bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I have the following variables

```
var1="Hedrickson"
var2="Johnson"
var3=
var4="Mulles"
```

The variables are surnames and are extracted from a csv. The variable content each time I get them can be different. Sometimes, a variable is empty, without any value, as is the case of var3.

I want to assign to empty variables the string value "empty".

I have tried a script but it seems this only works for integers and not strings

I have the following code:

```
for variable in "var1" "var2" "var3" "var4";do
   if  [ "${!variable}" -eq ""]; then
    eval $variable="empty"
   fi
done
```

Expected result :

```
var1="Hedrickson"
var2="Johnson"
var3="empty"
var4="Mulles"
```

Actual result:

```
error: integer expression expected.
```

Comment: Why, how are you "extracting variables" from a csv file? Why would you want to have multiple variables?

Comment: I am using these variables to put them in an html table that I create dynamically. Then send this as an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `-eq` is for arithmetic tests, for strings use `=`
2. Need a space before the `]`

So to sum up, this should work:
`[ "${!variable}" = "" ]`

Answer (score 2):

No need for an `if`. You could simply do a

```
: ${!variable:=empty}
```

If the variable being refered to, is non-empty, it keeps its value; otherwise it is set to empty.

Answer (score 0):

If your bash is recent enough (4.3 if I remember well) you can use a combination of a nameref and parameter substitution:

```
$ declare -n n
$ for n in "var1" "var2" "var3" "var4"; do : ${n:=empty}; done
```

With your example:

```
$ var1="Hedrickson"
$ var2="Johnson"
$ var3=
$ var4="Mulles"
$ declare -n n
$ for n in "var1" "var2" "var3" "var4"; do : ${n:=empty}; done
$ printf '%s\n' "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4"
Hedrickson
Johnson
empty
Mulles
```

You could also declare a function:

```
setEmpty() { local -n n; for n; do : ${n:=empty}; done; }
```

And then:

```
setEmpty "var1" "var2" "var3" "var4"
```

Warning: this will not work if the name of the nameref (`n` in my example) is the same as the name of one of your variables. Don't `setEmpty "n"`. Or use a less common name for your nameref.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bash syntax for setting default value if var is empty:

```
for variable in "${var1:-empty}" "${var2:-empty}" "${var3:-empty}" "${var4:-empty}";do
   echo "$variable"
done
```

This method is quite convenient when you set variables from args for example:

```
var1=${1:-John} # First name
var2=${2:-Doe}  # Last name
var3=${3:-42}   # Age
```